# Как отловить ошибку приходящую с бека?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, axios

Делаю запрос на логин пользователя и если юзер не найден возвращается 404 ошибка с:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, как вывести значение message? В catch не нашел данного ответа.
Сам код:

```js
loginUser(params: LoginTypeProps) {
  const { email, password, onSuccess } = params;
  return instance
    .post(`user/session`, {
      email,
      password,
    })
    .then(({ status, data }) => {
      if (status === 200 || status === 201) {
        onSuccess(data.payload.user.key);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Правильный ответ:

```js
.catch(({ response }) => response.data.message);
```

Comment: Как это сочетается с _"В catch не нашел данного ответа"_ в вопросе?

Comment: @Qwertiy JSON.stringify(error) не показал что в ответе есть message, но такая запись показала